# Probability that an arbitrary element of a field has a specific structure.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, finite-fields, hash-function

This question is related to :

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37351/encoding-an-element-in-r-rhr-way

that I asked couple of weeks ago. The difference is that I did not take the collision probability into account in that question.

---

Edit: A simpler version.

Assume $p'$ is a 40-bit value and $B=\{b_1,..,b_d\}$, where $b_i \in \mathbb{F}_{p'}$.

**Question1**: What is the probability that a random element of the field $\mathbb{F}_{p'}$ equals at least one of $B$'s element.

---

Application:

Assume we have a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a 100-bit prime number.

assume we have a set of 32-bit elements  $S=\{s_1,...,s_n\}$ defined over the field. We encode each element as $s'_1=s_1||h(s_1)$, where $h()$ is a (cryptographic) hash function and $|h(s_1)|=40$-bit.

So, for any arbitrary element, $r$, of the field we can check if it has the above structure as below:

1- $r=r_1||r_2$, if $|r_2|=40$-bit,  then we proceed to the next step.

2- $h(r_1)\stackrel{?}=r_2$

We know that with some probability two elements can have the same hash value. So, the above question can be re-written as follows:

**Question2**: What is the probability that an arbitrary element of the field has the above structure?

===================

Answer to question 1 would suffice.

Comment: Your post contains a lot of details, but it doesn't look like you're asking anything different from "what are the odds that a random number from $1$ to $p$ is an element of a given list of numbers". That is, the field, the hash function, the concatenation, they all seem entirely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thank you for the comments. In this case, the answer is $2^{-p}$, I guess.

Comment: Yopur random numbers have a length of 100 bits, while your $r$ has a length of 72 bits. Do you fill $r$ with trailing zeroes before you compare if to the random element?

Comment: @Dominik We first parse $r$ into $r_1$ and $r_2$ if $|r_2|=40$ then we check $h(r_1)=r_2$

Comment: Is $\frac{d}{2^{40}}$ the correct answer?